# Appcelerator hide multiple view with same class (Alloy)

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I'm looking for a way to show/hide multiple views with the same class.
Using jQuery is possible to do this usign:

```
$('.className').hide();
```

Is there any way to do that in appcelerator JS? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. You'll have to loop through the view array and call hide() on each one.

If you can add all the views to the same parent view, then you can hide just the parent view.

Comment: I would go for the parent view. It's quicker to hide/show them and its one command

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that , you can make `Dynamic Styles`  http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Dynamic_Styles

```
    $.addClass($.view, "hide"); // --> appears blue and 24dp
```

tss

```
".hide" : {
    visible: false
}
```